Что означает net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)?
Находясь на сайте vk.com посылаю на один из его cdn-сайтов запрос
await fetch(video).then(resp => resp.blob()).catch(e => { console.log(name, video, e); throw e; })

В большинстве случаев это работает, но иногда завершается ошибкой net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK):

При этом если смотреть сам запрос, то, насколько я понимаю, он успешен и нарушения CORS нет:

В консоли отображается вот так:

Если я нарушаю какие-то браузерные политики, то я не понимаю, какие. И об этом в консоли ничего нет.
Что означает эта ошибка?

никакое расширение не блочит? места на диске хватает?

можешь попробовать логи записать

@Grundy, расширений мало, рекламорезок нет. И если просто открыть ссылку в браузере, то файл скачивается. С логами попробую потом.

А не срабатывает ли ошибка на видео с размером 10Мб и более? вот тут пишут что есть ограничение в хроме. + проверить место на диске

@SwaD 1. Файлы с ошибками больше 10 МБ (от 10 до 14). 2. Есть успешные файлы с таким же размером и больше. Но в основном файлы меньше. 3. Свободное место на дисках: системный - 405 ГБ из 899 ГБ, диск с загрузками - 121 ГБ из 1.12 ТБ, диск с профилем хрома - 2,7 ГБ из 61 ГБ. На последнем вроде как не много места, но действительно ли может не хватать на десятиметровые файлы? 4. А как-то обойти требование на место на диске можно (если дело в нём)?

@SwaD, 5. Да, увеличение свободного места на диске с профилем хрома до 6 ГБ помогает. Можешь написать ответ про место. Пожалуй, про то, как скачать файл в обход этого ограничения я задам вопрос отдельно (хотя, может и сам придумаю). В таком случае галочка твоя.

Я с этим не работал, просто в нете нашел эту ошибку и решил поделиться(возможно, я капитан очевидность). Писать ответ о том, чего не знаю, не буду. Да и не для галочек я это все делаю.
